# How do I create nested properties on object literals using bracket notation?

Tags: javascript

The following works but I'm trying to find a way to omit the `arrayOfObjects[1]['testParent'] = {}` bit, imagine you wanted to add a value to an empty object that is nested 10 levels down, you would have to initialize each level with an empty `{}` first, I'm trying to find a workaround for that.

```js
let arrayOfObjects = [
{},
{},
{},
]

arrayOfObjects[1]['testParent'] = {}
arrayOfObjects[1]['testParent']['testKey'] = 'testValue'

// is there a way to do the above in one line, without having to initialize testParent with an empty object on line 7?

console.log(arrayOfObjects)
```

Comment: `arrayOfObjects[1]['testParent'] = {'testKey': 'testValue'}`, like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 arrayOfObjects[1] = {
    testParent: {
      testKey: 'testValue'
    }
 };
```

In fact, you can avoid the array indexer as well with something like:

```
 arrayOfObjects = [ 
    {},
    {
      testParent: {
        testKey: 'testValue'
      }
    },
    {}
 ];
```

Comment: This is not JSON.

Comment: @lonesomeday: because it is missing all the quotes, I suppose? I've removed the reference to JSON.

Comment: No, because JSON is a format for data serialisation. This is just standard Javascript object syntax. Downvote removed, in any case.

Comment: This seems like the way to go for an arbitrary nesting, keeping it simple, etc. `arrayOfObjects[1] = {testParent:{testParent:{testKey: 'testValue'}}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom method for this, using `reduce` that takes string and value and sets nested property.

```js
let arr = [{}, {}, {}]

function set(obj, key, value) {
  key.split(".").reduce((r, e, i, a) => {
    return r[e] || (r[e] = a[i + 1] ? {} : value)
  }, obj);
}

set(arr, "0.testParent.testKey", "testValue")
set(arr, "2.a.b.f", "value")
set(arr, "2.a.b.c", "value")

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a small helper can help you to omit the brackets:

```
const $ = (obj, key, ...keys) => key != undefined ? $(obj[key] || (obj[key] = {}), ...keys) : obj;
```

Usable as:

```
const arr = [];
$(arr, 1, "testParent").testKey = "testValue";
```